# I can't delete cookie with PHP

Tags: php, cookies

I can't delete a cookie with my php code. When I press `logout` the page refreshes but the cookie is still there.

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE["admin_login"])) {
    echo "Cookie: ".$_COOKIE["admin_login"]."<br>";
}
if (isset($_GET["logout"])) {
    setcookie("admin_login", "", time()-3600);
    unset($_COOKIE['admin_login']);

}
?>
<html>
<body>
    <a href="?logout">Logout</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look at the HTTP response headers, there should be a `setcookie` header. Check if it sets the date in the past.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're setting your own cookie rather than using the PHP $_SESSION? Not saying that there aren't legitimate reasons to roll your own session, but the $_SESSION is far preferable.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely happening because you're outputting data before setting cookie.

> setcookie() defines a cookie to be sent along with the rest of the HTTP headers. Like other headers, cookies must be sent **before any output** from your script (this is a protocol restriction).

```
if (isset($_COOKIE["admin_login"]))
    anything_that_doesnt_output_text(); // text was causing problem most likely.

if (isset($_GET["logout"]))
    setcookie("admin_login", "", time()-3600); // also, no unsetting
```

Comment: I am sorry friend, I did not saw this comment and yes, you are right, it works the way you say but at the end i switched from cookies from session. Thank you.

Comment: You could still mark it as an answer though, since this is the answer to your question. Switching to sessions is a work around.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers. After finding no solution i tried to switch to SESSION.

After some research i made it works great. Thank you all for helping me.

If someone is interested, here is my final code.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_GET["logout"])) {
    session_unset(); 
    session_destroy(); 
    header("Location: ../login.php");    
}
if (isset($_SESSION["admin_login_session"])) {
    echo "Cookie: ".$_SESSION["admin_login_session"]."<br>";
} else {
    header("Location: ../login.php");
}

?>
<html>
<body>
    <a href="?logout">Logout</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Honestly, you did not find my simple answer working? Please leave a comment on my answer so I know if it's ok or or if I should remove it.